# In postfix how parent_domain_matches_subdomains helps rejecting mail for subdomains?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, e-mailrelay

Based on the standard configuration given in https://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#firewall the `parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list, smtpd_access_maps` should help in rejecting mails from subdomains. Say if I have a single line in my access maps which allows only my domain emails in access maps it will make the matter worse by matching sub domains with that line too, isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

The example does not reject mail **from** subdomains, but mail **for** subdomains.

> Lines 1-10: - - and accept mail from outside **for** "user@example.com" **but not for** "user@anything.example.com". The magic is in lines 4-5.

The [`parent_domain_matches_subdomains`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#parent_domain_matches_subdomains) is:

> A list of Postfix features where the pattern "`example.com`" also matches subdomains of example.com, instead of requiring an explicit "`.example.com`" pattern. This is planned backwards compatibility: eventually, all Postfix features are expected to require explicit ".example.com" style patterns when you really want to match subdomains.

By default (`postconf -d | grep parent_`) there are much more backwards compatible features:

```
parent_domain_matches_subdomains =
    debug_peer_list,
    fast_flush_domains,
    mynetworks,
    permit_mx_backup_networks,
    qmqpd_authorized_clients,
    relay_domains,
    smtpd_access_maps`
```

This [example](https://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#firewall) is limiting them to `debug_peer_list smtpd_access_maps`, removing many including the `relay_domains` that is meaningful in that situation. If you wish to also remove the `smtpd_access_maps` just do it. It is an example.